# Strange behavior of if() inside map() in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement

Using map() I wrote a simple function that was supposed to return 'yes' if x is 1, 'no' if x is 2, 'maybe' if x is 3.

```
map(
  .x = c(1,2,3),
  .f = function(x) {
    if (x==1) y= 'yes'
    if (x==2) y='no'
    if (x==3) y='maybe'})
```

I expected to get a list with 'yes', 'no', 'maybe', yes I got:

```
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
[1] "maybe"
```

So it seems that every if() is evaluated and only the last one is returned, which is NULL when x is 1 or 2. My question is why? I would expected if() to behave like in the global environment:

```
x = 1
    if (x==1) y='yes'
    if (x==2) y='no'
    if (x==3) y='maybe'})
y
[1] "yes"
```

Comment: if a function has no explicit return value (i.e. if you are not using `return` to return something) R returns the last evaluated expression.
In your case `f(1)` and `f(2)` both return `NULL` because the last evaluated expression is `if (2 == 3) ... `.
Any easy fix would be to add `return(y)` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning a new value to `y` three times. Use `else` to keep make it one expression.

```r
map(
  .x = c(1,2,3),
  .f = function(x) {
    if (x==1) y = 'yes'
    else if (x==2) y = 'no'
    else if (x==3) y = 'maybe'})

#[[1]]
#[1] "yes"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "no"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "maybe"
```

Comment: I also assign a value to y 3 times when running the if() outside the map(), yet the y stays 'yes' (see the last line of my question)

Answer (score 1):

R is an expressions-based language. Expressions have value. (Almost) everything is an expression. Meaning everything ultimately has one value.
The function body in the map ends up only having one value, the last if-statement.

So add `else`, e.g.

```r
map(
  .x = c(1, 2, 3),
  .f = function(x) {
    if (x == 1)
      y = 'yes'
    else if (x == 2)
      y = 'no'
    else if (x == 3)
      y = 'maybe'
  }
)
```